# Does WSProxy Calls consume SFMC API limits?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, marketingcloudapi, wsproxy

We have a use-case where we have to find out all the Data extensions present in a Business unit. We can achieve this by using the WSProxy Retrieve option or SSJS RetrieveRequest approach. As the performance is better in WSPRoxy so we are leaning towards using WSProxy but the only concern that we have is does WSProxy calls consume SFMC APIs? If it does then we have to go with the SSJS approach as we do not want to consume SFMC API limits for this implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the answer is 'No'. I have done a similar solution for 30 business units and also fetching the count of rows in the Data Extensions using the undocumented REST API. The automation was running on daily basis along with other BAU Operations. We never hit any limits or faced any issues. So, you should not have any problem. The only thing to consider is the timeout for SSJS activity if you plan to do this via Automation Studio. We split the automation in 5 activities having processed 6 BUs at a time.

Comment: Thanks Swati for the suggestions. Have you found any documentation on this topic in any Salesforce Help portals regarding if the WSProxy or SSJS Retrieve calls consume SFMC APIs or not?

Comment: No, and as I mentioned, I don't think there are API limits in this regard